# sorting icon issue in datatable

Tags: javascript, html

How to fix datatables sorting arrows not showing in header, as Iam using the code, from the link that mention here. Everything is working good, pop up and all, but I am not able to fix the sorting icon

Comment: You said from the link that mention here. Where?

Comment: This one
https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/t53cyutt/42/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is the answer

I think you didn't included libraries for `datatable`

For including `jquery datatable` libraries, copy following lines and put it in `head` tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

#### You can find Woking code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J0J5R3d1JMYQEQOx0vbUtI-PIpR6GcVN/view?usp=sharing